# Showing wrong view in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and trying to get index page, i am using following routes

```
Route::get('/', 
        ['as' => 'home_page',
         'uses' => 'Controller@index']);
```

and index function in controller looks like this:

```
public function index()
    {
       return view('index');
    }
```

But when I visit `mydomain.com`, I get a different view than `index.blade.php`.
and it is fine when I use `mydomain.com/?` or on my local server.

I have searched everywhere in my code and in a google, but didn't found anything, any help?

*ie: let me know if any further information required.*

Comment: do you have `index.blade.php` file inside view directory ?

Comment: yes, I do have, that's why it is running when i use `?` suffix with my index URL

Comment: Then it seems strange problem

Comment: exactly, it was working very fine yesterday

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are calling the right controller, and this dont have a specific middleware blocking the acess to your `index` method and `index.blade.php` is inside view folder.

If all of this is fine try this code on your rotes file:

```
    Route::get('', function () {
    return view('index');
   })
```

Comment: Selected controller is a right one,
Same error facing with this code... 
Note: the Right view is loading with the suffix `?` in url

Comment: What view you get in  your domain.com/ ?

Comment: Actually, this is a very unusual.
i am getting a view from another subdomain.

Comment: Did you check your `.env` file and make sure your  `APP_URL=` is correct?
 Seems like the problem is coming from your configurations.

Comment: Nice, You should use  `php artisan config:cache` because this command will make your actual configs in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
First use the make:controller Artisan command to create a controller file. let's say it is homeController.

```
php artisan make:controller homeController
```

Then in the homeController file write your code to get the view.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class homeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       return view('index');
    }
}
```

Then define a route to this controller.

```
Route::get('/', 'homeController@index');
```

For more information please refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers

Comment: This is not an answer to what I was asking, 
but I have fixed my error with flushing the cache.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There was a cached view saved on my server, I used
`php artisan cache:clear` and it got fixed. Thank you everyone for the support.